# How to stop many process like unicorn and sidekiq using single command in certain environment

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I remotely access remotely EC2 instance, i will stop and start unicorn and sidekiq by following commands

```
 cap development unicorn:start
 cap development unicorn:stop
 cap development sidekiq:start
 cap development sidekiq:stop
```

how can i do this using single command to stop and start these unicorn and sidekiq. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a simple bash script.

As an example we will use `/root/startup.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
cap development unicorn:start
cap development unicorn:stop
cap development sidekiq:start
cap development sidekiq:stop
```

The make sure the script is executable:

```
$ chmod +x /root/startup.sh
```

Now you can run it and it will execute all the commands one after another:

```
$ /root/startup.sh
```

Comment: Fine but i need other than running a shell script.